# Native query in Spring Boot with WHERE condition for tuple in list

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jdbc, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

When sending plain SQL to PostgreSQL like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE things (
    id      BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    foo     BIGINT NOT NULL,
    bar     BIGINT NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO things VALUES (9900, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO things VALUES (9901, 3, 4);
INSERT INTO things VALUES (9902, 1, 4);
SELECT * FROM things WHERE foo IN (1, 2);
SELECT * FROM things WHERE (foo, bar) IN (VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4));
```

it works as expected.

However when trying to do the same thing using Spring Boot, it fails. Here is my minimal example (Kotlin):

The entity:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.AbstractPersistable
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.Table

@Entity
@Table(name = "things")
class Thing(
        val foo: Long,
        val bar: Long
) : AbstractPersistable<Long>()
```

The repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query

interface ThingRepository : JpaRepository<Thing, Long> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM things WHERE foo IN (1, 2);")
    fun selectNativeByFoo(): Iterable<Thing>

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM things WHERE (foo, bar) IN (VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4));")
    fun selectNativeByFooAndBar(): Iterable<Thing>
}
```

A call to `selectNativeByFoo` works fine, but calling `selectNativeByFooAndBar` fails with the following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [SELECT * FROM things WHERE (foo, bar) IN (VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4));]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement


Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Invalid parameter count for "VALUES", expected count: "1"; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM things WHERE (foo, bar) IN (VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4)); [7001-197]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your SQL experiment, you're using PostgreSQL. In your exception, the exception is a org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException, showing that you're not using PostgreSQL, but H2. My guess is that your actual production database is PostgreSQL. I would thus run tests against PostgreSQL, not H2.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, you are absolutely right. I am using H2. However in my `application.yaml` I have `spring.datasource.url: jdbc:h2:mem:db;MODE=PostgreSQL`, and I (maybe too naively) assumed, this suffices to make it work in a compatible way.

Comment: Test it with the real thing. My guess is that indeed, you were too naive :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55315775/native-query-in-spring-boot-with-where-condition-for-tuple-in-list?noredirect=1#comment97358959_55315775) by [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet), I was able to solve it.

The syntax used

```
SELECT * FROM things WHERE (foo, bar) IN (VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4));
```

is only supported by real PostgreSQL, not by H2, which I was using for my tests, even with

```
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:h2:mem:db;MODE=PostgreSQL
```

Changing it to

```
SELECT * FROM things WHERE (foo, bar) IN ((1, 2), (3, 4));
```

makes it work in both, real Postgres and H2 in Postgres mode.

---

Another option is to switch to [`embedded-database-spring-test`](https://github.com/zonkyio/embedded-database-spring-test) and use it's embedded Postgres for testing. Then the original syntax (using `VALUES`) also works.